# OpenShift oc user is logged out after a while

Tags: openshift, aws-cloudformation

I am using a cloudformation script, 
where I successfully execute `oc login -u user -p password`

My script goes on and after a while I face problems, 
because I seem not to be logged in anymore.
`$(oc whoami)` gives an empty space.

What could be the reason, that the login is lost after a while?

Answer (score 3):

When you authenticate to the OpenShift API as a user you are assigned an oauth token which will expire after some time. This value is set in the `master-config.yaml` file. Default location `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml`. This value is set under `oauthConfig.tokenConfig.accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds`, default value is `86400` or 24 hours

Also take a look at `oauthConfig.sessionMaxAgeSeconds` which could be the issue you are hitting given the time you mentioned in your comment.

If you need to get a token that won't expire you could look at creating a [service account](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/service_accounts.html). This may be the preferred option if you intend to automate this.

Comment: Thnx. But in my case login expires after 30 min. Do you know, where one can learn about the expiration of generated tokens? E.g. about the fact that the tokens do expire?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specifics, really it is the implementation of OAuth. Linking to some high level auth details from [OpenShift docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/architecture/additional_concepts/authentication.html)